# Protege 5 - Specifying primary key and foregin key

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key

Protege 5 - Specifying primary key and foregin key

Can you help me to place a primary key and foreign key for the following scene.

Thing
 Person
   Staff
   Student
 Course
    Maths
    CS

Staff has :StaffID, Name

Student: StudentID, Name

Object Properties : Studies, Teaches

FOllowing issues should be solved for me

1- I need to make StaffID, StudentID as primary Keys
2- I also wanted to make these as foreignkey relationship ( i dont know
whether its correct to say that)

3- Once primary key is defined, when i add individuals with same StaffID or
StudentID, how and where to check ? i mean to show there is a duplicated
data is added.

Please help me